# Create project from approved estimate with task budgets?

Tags: invoices, project-management

I keep bumping my head against this freelancer/contractor workflow issue.

I'd like to be able to create a project from an approved estimate with a click or workflow or zap, along with the amount estimated for each task (or service). All of the invoicing software I've been using for estimates doesn't do this. I have to copy and paste into a new project once an estimate is approved to then start working on the project.

And I want to make sure that I'm staying within the estimated effort for each task on the estimate. So I'd love it if the project has a budget for time and I get an alert when I'm within 90% of it.

My projects sometimes have set services and a number of added on unique tasks. So some software I've used adds a new service every time I create a task, and I don't need that. Or only have tasks at the service level, so I have a bunch of line items to group and add up manually for invoices which is time consuming and can introduce errors.

I'm not sure what I'm not getting here, but I can't seem to find a system or set of systems working together to do this.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Anyone know of an app or software that does this or ones that work together to get there?

Comment: I think you described [Harvest](https://www.getharvest.com/features). For solo or small teams it's great.

Comment: Do you have other software that this must interface with?

Comment: If you are making a website use [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/) or [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)
If making a mobile app use [NativeScript Framework](https://nativescript.org/)

Comment: Thanks @Dario, Harvest is solving that for me. Unfortunately Freshbooks does not import timesheets, so I have to solve that another way.